# laravel 4 rapyd model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel, use the complement Rapyd Laravel, sent me the following problem:

```
[2014-09-16 02:26:01] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant Autor - assumed 'Autor'' in C:\wamp\www\prueba3\app\controllers\AutorController.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\prueba3\app\controllers\AutorController.php(11): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Use of undefine...', 'C:\wamp\www\pru...', 11, Array)
```

I hope you can help me, below image link

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1448x815q90/674/1YVKfP.png

When this use, works well:

```
$set = DataSet::source("Bib_Autor");
```

When this use, does not work

```
$set = DataSet::source(Autor);
```

Im new... ty

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to change this:

```
$set = DataSet::source(Autor);
```

to this

```
$set = DataSet::source("Autor");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate a model or use the Eloquent query builder

```
$set = DataSet::source(new Autor);

$set = DataSet::source(DB::table("autors"));
```

as explained here:
https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel/wiki/DataSet